# "Tree View" using XSLT / XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I try to build "tree" which should look sth like this

```
-group1
    *jobA
    *jobB
-group2
    *jobC
-group3
    *jobD
```

but now using code which is below I'm getting

```
-group1
     *group2
            +group3
```

From this i get list of groups and when I call template I want to get list of jobs in each group

```
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <xsl:variable name="unique-list" select="DEFTABLE/TABLE/JOB[not(@GROUP=following::JOB/@GROUP)]" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="$unique-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#{@GROUP}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@GROUP" />
                                        </a>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="ListJob">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="group" select="@GROUP"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </li>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
```

And my template

```
<xsl:template name="ListJob">
    <xsl:param name="group"/>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="DEFTABLE/TABLE/JOB[@GROUP=$group]">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="@JOBNAME"/> 
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML files looks sth like this

```
<DEFTABLE>
<TABLE>
<JOB NAME="jobA" GROUP="group1"/>
</TABLE>
</DEFTABLE>
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please include enough XML sample data so that it's possible to *actually* build a tree from it. And then include the precise XML/HTML you want to generate for that XML sample.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I've just solve this problem :)

Comment: @pm_li Then delete your question. -- P.S. Your approach is wrong to begin with - see:http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html